# Selenium Agent Operating Systems

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm new to Selenium testing, and I have question about browser agents.

I've written a script that I want to test with IE8 on XP, IE8 and IE9 on Windows 7. I know it is possible to define the version of the browser, but I don't know whether it is possible to define the OS version or not.

I'm asking this question because I'm using Selenium Grid on a CentOS box.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following values

[image]

[**Doc**](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Platform.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can define the OS by setting the Platform capability, like so

```
capability.setPlatform(“LINUX”);
```

You can read more about it here - http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Comment: I saw this link as well, but couldn't find list of parameters I can pass to setPlatform. Java function accepts Android, VISTA, WINDOWS, WIN8, MAC, UNIX, VISTA, and XP as parameter. At least that's what Eclipse recommends me.

Comment: So I am not sure where is the confusion ?

Comment: I saw this lane  -browser  browserName=firefox,version=3.6,platform=LINUX from that link, and was wondering what were the other parameters I can pass. Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI link broken @ July 2020